# FFMPEG add black bars to a image if the video input is not 16:9

Tags: ffmpeg

So I'm playing with ffmpeg and I have the command currently:

```
"ffmpeg_path -ss seek_time -i input_video_path -vframes 1 -f mjpeg output_image_path 2<&1"
```

The issue that I'm facing is that for example I have a vertical video from a mobile phone the output image will be streched to 16:9, what I would like to do is to add black bars to the side of the image if the input is not in a 16:9 format.

Any suggestions or ideas on how I could do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [pad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad-1). The same documentation includes an exact example of what you want:

> - Pad the input to get a final w/h ratio of 16:9:
>
> ```
> pad="ih*16/9:ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"
> ```

The filter can be specified using the `-vf` option:

```
ffmpeg -ss <time> -i <input> -vframes 1 -f mjpeg -vf pad="ih*16/9:ih:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" <output>
```